# When do Applicatives run their effects?

Tags: haskell, applicative, side-effects, arrows

Under ["Why do Static Arrows generalise Arrows?" post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62849399/why-do-s..?), we often spoke of `Applicative` running side-effects before the application of the function-in-the-functor to the value-in-the-functor.

Also, [danidiaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1364288/danidiaz) used this fact to show that `Arrow` is not equivalent to `Applicative` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24669525/11143763) under ["Arrows are exactly equivalent to applicative functors?" question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24668313/11143763).

How is this property formalised?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `Applicative`, that can be justified through parametricity. Consider...

```
(&*&) :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f (a, b)
```

... which is the counterpart to `(<*>)` in [the monoidal presentation of `Applicative`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia#Alternative_formulation). Restricted to functions, the free theorem for `(&*&)` is:

```
fmap g u &*& fmap h v = fmap (bimap g h) (u &*& v)
```

(The free theorem is actually more general than that, as it allows for relations that aren't functions to play the roles of `g` and `h`.)

The free theorem means that if we change the values-in-the-functor of `u` or `v`, the result of `(&*&)` will only be affected by its corresponding values-in-the-functor being changed in the same manner. In other words, as far as `(&*&)` is concerned the values-in-the-functor have no influence over the applicative effects, which is what you intended to establish.